# Checking URL to replace string

Tags: php, jquery, string, url, replace

I'm trying to replace the text in an header tag in a specific page by checking to see if that URL contains a unique string, then changing the header tag to another word. This is my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var hasQueryString = document.URL.indexOf(‘shop/?orderby=date’);
    if (hasQueryString > 1) $(‘h1’).html(‘New’);
});
```

So my site is www.site.com, and when the user is on www.site.com/shop/?orderby=date, I want the text in the h1 tag to be replaced with 'new'. I'm using WordPress and trying and enqueue the script (which I'm pretty sure I've done correctly) but it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your JavaScript. It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/evseyx7g/ it may be something else - do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: is this code waiting to fire until after the page loads (or at least until the h1 tag has been rendered?). If not it's attempting to populate a node that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: hasQueryString conditional should probably be `hasQueryString !== -1` `-1` indicates not found, anything other than that indicates it exists.

Comment: I see that you are not using quotes. Change `’` to `'`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're calling this code prior to the completion of the page loading and there is no `h1` node to populate with text.  Or  does your matched string start at char 0 or 1? why are you looking for > 1 ?